# Kubuntu 14.10, updates gives GPG error

Tags: apt, updates, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 14.10. About a week or so ago, I noticed that doing a 'sudo apt-get update' gives me the following error at the end.

```
Fetched 16.0 MB in 24s (650kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CFBCA7A67412649C
```

Any ideas? Some Google searching reveals an old bug that seems to have already been fixed so I don't know if it's the same problem as mine or not.

Comment: Could you add any more information, such as what source that is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CFBCA7A67412649C
```

and then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I couldn't tell where it was coming from by looking at the error but by importing the key I saw the PPA it was from.